# Interpreting linear mixed effect model results with log transformed dependent variable and log transformed predictor w/ normal predictors as well

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, predictive-models, logarithm, back-transformation

I have a linear mixed effect model that I built using longitudinal country level data to help me predict TB incidence based on country level diabetes prevalence, HIV incidence, prevalence of malnutrition, and income per capita. I found my model diagnostics improved drastically when I log transformed TB incidence, HIV incidence, and income per capita. I am now wondering how I plug known values of HIV incidence, income, malnutrition and diabetes into my model to get a measure of TB incidence that is back in its original units and no longer log transformed. My code is below, please let me know if there is anything I can add to make my question clearer.

```
AFR_inc_multi <- lmer(log_inc_AFR ~ `Malnutrition_prev ` + 
                       log_HIV_AFR + 
                    log_income + DM_prev +
                    (1|country), data=tbdata_AFR, REML = FALSE)
summary(AFR_inc_multi)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use 
 Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: log_inc_AFR ~ `Malnutrition_prev ` + log_HIV_AFR + 
                    log_income +      DM_prev + (1 | country)


Data: tbdata_AFR
 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
-45.9    -21.3     29.9    -59.9      240 
Scaled residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-2.73917 -0.49148  0.05955  0.56609  2.55527 
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
country  (Intercept) 0.67357  0.8207
Residual             0.02319  0.1523 
Number of obs: 247, groups:  country, 31
Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|) 
(Intercept)            5.236917   0.387370 227.927563  13.519  < 2e-16 ***
`Malnutrition_prev `  -0.003530   0.002156 221.745552  -1.638  0.10287
log_HIV_AFR            0.224215   0.026431 242.618976   8.483 2.18e-15 ***
log_income            -0.138508   0.038422 239.064197  -3.605  0.00038 ***
DM_prev               -0.003636   0.006753 220.545834  -0.538  0.59083 
-----
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) `Ml_ ` l_HIV_ lg_ncm
`Mlntrtn_ ` -0.385
log_HIV_AFR -0.671 -0.008
log_income  -0.876  0.423  0.498
DM_prev      0.122 -0.089 -0.041 -0.250
```

Comment: It might be best to use `emmeans` and its [machinery for bias adjustment](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj). Other than that, just take the income and HIV_AFR values you want to predict and log-transform them ...

Comment: Thank you for the link! So just to make sure I have it right to get my prediction for incidence back to normal units I can just do
exp(TB Incidence) = (-0.0035*Malnutrition) + exp(0.224*HIV incidence) + exp(-0.139*income) + (-0.0036*DM prevalence) + 5.23?

Comment: As an aside, why not leave the variables as is and use a nonlinear mixed model?

Comment: I looked into it briefly but I've never used non-linear mixed models before, nor have I learned about them formally in a class or job, so I didn't feel totally comfortable trying to teach them to myself because this is a time limited project I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to predict TB incidence for HIV prevalence 0.05, income 10000, diabetes prevalence 0.04, malnutrition prevalence 0.1

```r
pred_data = data.frame("Malnutrition_prev "=0.1, log_HIV_AFR = log(0.05),
      log_income = log(10000), DM_prev = 0.04)
p0 <- predict(AFR_inc_multi, newdata = pred_data), re.form = NA)
exp(p0)
```

will give you the *geometric mean* prediction, independent of country. If you want to do *bias correction* (i.e. get the arithmetic mean), you need to compute `exp(mean + var/2)`, or

```r
v <- c(VarCorr(AFR_inc_multi)$country)
exp(p0 + v/2)
```

You can also use the built-in machinery from [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj) to handle the bias correction and back-transformation of your response (I think you'll still have to deal with log-transforming the predictor variables yourself ...)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful, I really appreciate it

Comment: Coming back to this question late, but if I wanted to make a prediction for a specific country than would my code look the same except for

`re.form = NA #would instead become 
re.form=(1|country)` 

and I specify the country name in the data.frame step? In other words would I have to do anything different in the bias correction?

Comment: Nothing would change about the bias correction. `re.form = NULL` is equivalent to "include all RE terms that were in the original model"